# Creating dataframe rows from keys of underlying dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
'A'  'B'  'Dict'
 a    f    {'k1': 'v1', 'k2': 'v2'}
 b    h    {}
 c    g    {'k3': 'v3'}
 …    …    …
```

And I would like the following:

```
'A'  'B'  'Keys'
 a    f    k1
 a    f    k2
 c    g    k3
 …    …    …
```

That is, getting the keys of a dict to make the rows of the new dataframe. The dict may be empty or contain arbitrary number of elements.

Here is the solution I am using now. It works, but seems to be quite inefficient and not very pythonic…

```
my_list = []

for row in subset.iterrows():
  for key in row[1][2].keys():
    my_list.append((row[1][0], row[1][1], key))

new_df = pd.DataFrame(my_list)
```

Thanks in advance for your ideas!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or you can `set_index()`

```
df.set_index(['A','B'])['Dict'].apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index()
```

Comment: You'll need to set both A and B as the index :)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yep :-) , just too lazy to create column B :-)

Comment: Hey, thanks, but I get 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Dict'

What am I missing ?

Comment: @SilverDuck change to `df.set_index(['A','B'])['Dict'].apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index()`

Comment: How okay, I see what you tried to do now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SilverDuck Well and good you accepted this, but keep in mind `apply` + `pd.Series` is pretty slow.

Comment: Actually, now that you said it, I timed them:
For 5000 rows (with about 2 keys per dict) The apply Series took 45 seconds, the multi index 35 and mine 1,5. So even if mine’s not that beautiful, I’m gonna have to keep it to work on my final dataset.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need `stack` here:

```
pd.DataFrame(
   df.Dict.tolist(), 
   index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.A, df.B])
).stack().reset_index()

   A  B level_2   0
0  a  f      k1  v1
1  a  f      k2  v2
2  c  g      k3  v3
```